# Trigger a svn android buiild using Jenkins

Tags: android, svn, build, jenkins

Hi friends can any one suggest me how to trigger a svn android build using jenkins..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are two ways of doing it, as described in [this document](http://jenkins-ci.org/node/212): you can either poll SVN repository or write a post-commit hook. You'll need [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) (which is part of Jenkins distribution - but just in case check that it is installed and enabled).

You configure your build by checking *Subversion* radio box in *Source code management* system and then specifying what to check out and where to put it in your working copy (there are '?' icons to the right - use them for help). If you use polling you'll also need to check *Poll SCM* box in *Build Triggers* section and specify polling schedule (again, use '?' help).

Comment: Thanks for giving me a suggestion, now i wanted to know about how to trigger auto build also.

Comment: What do you mean by 'auto' builds?

Comment: nightly builds, the build should run auto, we will set timing, it will automatically trigger the build like cronjob

Comment: Check *Build Periodically* box in Build Triggers section and specify the schedule.

Comment: need to execute a shell script, my shell script is in svn like for example, i mentioned svn repository http://<serverip:>/abc/ so the code is check out to default path /opt/ubersvn/jenkins/build_tools/ my scrip is in build_tools how to execute this script,in "Build" i option i have selected the option "Execute Shell" and directly i given the ./build_ics.sh(script name) if i give the exact path i am getting failure notification.

Comment: There could be several problems here. The first thing to verify is that build_ics.sh is indeed found in the job workspace. To check where the workspace is - run `echo ${WORKSPACE}` in a separate shell build step and examine the console output.